# user vs. computer- who can get closest to secret number

Tags: javascript

- I am brand new to Stack OverFlow. I am working on a create your own lab that asks to create four main functions. The point of the lab is for the user to select a number between 0 and 9, and the computer selects a number at random between 0 and 9, and whoever is closest to the secretNumber that is created at random, wins.
- Verbiage from lab:
  " In this project, you’ll write four functions in script.js. We’ve provided some additional JavaScript code in game.js that will call your functions based on user interactions, but you don’t need to look at game.js and shouldn’t edit it if you want your project to work as intended. As you complete this project, make sure that all of your functions are named exactly as specified so that they can be called correctly when the game is played.The "game.js" file has CSS and HTML that integrates into this lab. "

I have the following code already:

```
        let humanScore = 0;
        let computerScore = 0;
        let currentRoundNumber = 1;

        // First function - creates random number between 0 and 9
        const generateTarget = () => {
          return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        };

        /*Second function > Math.abs() - absolute value? Not sure if I need to use this or not, 
        and I believe this is where I am having the biggest issue */

        const compareGuesses = humanGuess, computerGuess, secretNumber => {
          if (humanGuess === secretNumber {
            return true;
          }
          else if (computerGuess === secretNumber {
            return false;
          } 
          else if (humanGuess === computerGuess) {
            return true;
          }
        };

        //Third function
        const updateScore = 'human' || 'computer' => {
          if (compareGuesses == true) {
            console.log(humanScore += 1);
          }
          if (compareGuesses == false) {
            console.log(computerScore += 1);
          }
        };

        //Fourth function
        const advanceRound = () => {
          console.log(currentRoundNumber += 1);
        };
```

- Right now, It is not doing anything, and it should run and get a random number for the computer, and then compare it to the number I selected, and finally see who is closest to the secretNumber. Greatly appreciate any help or hints on this!

Comment: Your JS code has few syntax error, I am afraid whether it runs or not. Please fix those.

Comment: Your browser is useful for debugging your code. On chrome you can right-click and click the "inspect" button. You can see basic errors such as syntax errors in the console tab (some idea with other browsers) which will help you debug your code. I suggest you look over the [arrow function syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and when to use `()` around your function's parameters.

Comment: If possible look at the JS fiddle `https://jsfiddle.net/asutosh/we53tmj9/4/` and fix the syntax error here,  then it would be easy for us to fix it.